# about direct3d about method of D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx

Tags: c++, directx, textures, direct3d

Can i create a texture object with a gif picture?
I try to do this and succeed compiling and linking, but fail to start.

```
if(D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(g_D3DDevice, file, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    D3DFMT_UNKNOWN, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, D3DX_DEFAULT,
    D3DX_DEFAULT,  colorkey,   &info,  NULL, 
    &m_textureList[index].image) != D3D_OK) return false;
```

Maybe I should change some parameters?
Sorry for new of direct3d. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i create a texture object with a gif picture?

[Not with `D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This function supports the following file formats: .bmp, .dds, .dib, .hdr, .jpg, .pfm, .png, .ppm, and .tga. See `D3DXIMAGE_FILEFORMAT`.

Comment: You could try [loading the GIF with GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535411(v=vs.85).aspx) and then converting that in-memory representation to a Direct3D Texture. GDI+ should be able to give you the raw bits that represent the image.